# ROS2 Nav2 Not Starting with namespace

Tags: ros, nav2

I have a ROS2 workspace with a package that is functioning properly. This package starts Nav2 using the bringup_launch script.

Now I want to start Nav2 with a given namespace. However, when I pass the namespace argument (as below), everything starts correctly but the Nav2 stack doesn't show any info in the command line and also shows up as unknown in RViz (It hasn't started). The other nodes being launched along with Nav2 start correctly with the namespace argument (ex. robot_state_publisher and robot_localization)

Nav2 is started as follows:

```
    nav2_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(nav2_launch_dir, 'bringup_launch.py')),
        launch_arguments = {'map': static_map_path, 
                            'params_file': nav2_params_path, 
                            'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time'), 
                            'autostart': 'true',
                            'namespace': 'abc',
                            'use_namespace': 'true'}.items()
    )
```

Any Ideas why? Also, can someone please provide the correct way to launch Nav2 if the given approach is not correct?

ROS2 Distribution: humble

Comment: For reference, the following comments show how the other nodes are started

Comment: remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'), ('/tf_static', 'tf_static')]

Comment: robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('model')]), 
                     'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')}],
        remappings=remappings,
        namespace='abc'
    )

Comment: map_odom_publisher = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        output="screen" ,
        arguments=["--x", "0", "--y", "0", "--z", "0", "--roll", "0", "--pitch", "0", "--yaw", "0", "--frame-id", "map", "--child-frame-id", "odom"],
        remappings=remappings,
        namespace='abc'
    )

Comment: robot_localization_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='ekf_node',
        name='ekf_filter_node',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config', 'ekf.yaml'), 
                    {'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')}],
        remappings=remappings,
        namespace='abc'
    )

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach that my fellow student used here:

- https://github.com/igrak34/TurtleBot2-on-ROS2/blob/main/turtlebot2_nav/launch/nav2.launch.py
- https://github.com/igrak34/TurtleBot2-on-ROS2/blob/main/turtlebot2_nav/param/nav2_params.yaml

In `nav2_params.yaml` you have `odom_topic: /namespace/odom` etc.

In the Nav2 launch file you have

...

```
use_namespace=LaunchConfiguration('use_namespace')
namespace=LaunchConfiguration('namespace')
```

...

```
namespaced_params= ReplaceString(
    source_file=param_path, replacements={"/namespace":("/",namespace)}
)

namespaced_rviz_config_file = ReplaceString(
    source_file=rviz_config_file, replacements={"/tb2": ("/", namespace)})
```

Remember about preparing the RViz file:

- https://github.com/igrak34/TurtleBot2-on-ROS2/blob/main/turtlebot2_nav/rviz/namespaced_nav2.rviz

We found this way the easiest.

Approaches without modifying the YAML had problems with some nodes not in the namespaces as far as I remember (at least in the case of the TurtleBot2 upgrade to ROS2). Maybe these problems are fixed now.

Comment: In my code, I am not using a scan topic in the configuration file (no laser scanner) and I am not using rviz. So the namespaced_... = ReplaceString(...) is not required in my code.

Comment: +1. I filed [navigation2#3610](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3610) to potentially move that functionality to broader general public.